# Hapijs content-type has application/jwt giving 415 unsupported media type

Tags: hapi.js, hapi

Hi I am using hapijs version 17 for REST API development, when we are using Content-Type as application/jwt, we are getting 415 http error code Unsupported Media Type .. details below ..

Could someone recommend how to set the Content-type header to application/jwt?

```
server.route({
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/hello',
            config: {
                payload: {
                  allow: 'application/jwt'
                }
              },
            handler: (request, h) => {
                console.log("req------------->",request)
                return "hello";
            }
        });
```

we get the following error in response:

```
{
    "statusCode": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Unsupported Media Type"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `parse: false` to use these content types. Something like this

```
payload: {
              "parse": false,
              allow: 'application/jwt'
            }
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish Modi for your quick response I will try this.

Comment: This solution is working fine for me Thanks, Ashish Modi.

Comment: @Ashish How to use it with express?